# Why does a button cause my whole web page to reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a web page I'm working on with jQuery.  I'm getting erratic behavior from some elements on my page: Every time a button, any button, on the page is clicked, the page refreshes.

The page must somehow be running some code that reloads that page any time a button is clicked.

I'm completely stumped trying to figure out where the code is getting bound to the click handler, so I would like to know if it is possible to enumerate, at run-time, a list of handlers attached to a button.

**Update:** After reading the answers given below, I changed a line in my page:

```
<button id="btnSaveAndContinue" class="button" tabindex="290">Save and Continue</button>
```

to this:

```
<input type='button' id="btnSaveAndContinue" class="button" tabindex="290" value='Save and Continue' />
```

Comment: If you're on Google Chrome or Safari, the Developer Tools will definitely help with that a lot. Just use Inspect Element.

Comment: The default behavior of a button is to submit the form it is within.  Are you sure that's not what's happening?

Comment: This is very odd because in the current version of the web program on the production server, we don't have this problem. I've just noticed the problem on a new version of the program on my dev server.

Comment: If it is a button causing the submit you can change the button type from "submit" to "button".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the default behaviour of a button. If you want to change it, do something like this:

```
$("button selector").click( function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Or better yet, `preventDefault`.  Returning false also stops propagation, which you shouldn't do unless you actually want to.

Comment: Good call. Updated to use `preventDefault` instead of `return false`.

Comment: +1 for `preventDefault`. Better still, if you actually want to stop propagation, use `stopPropagation`

Comment: Why on earth is this the default??

Answer (score 0):

You have to stop the default behavior for the event with `event.preventDefault()` within your `click` handler.

See [this](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)