# Qualtrics: Empty button appended by jquery refreshes page

Tags: javascript, jquery, qualtrics

I'm attempting to implement an experiment in Qualtrics, but I've run up against this wall.

A button appended to a qualtrics question using JQuery will refresh the page, regardless of whether or not `.click` or `.event` have been defined. In my design this has the effect of wiping all the responses a participant has given up until that point, which is probably the last thing I want to happen.

My code is too complicated (a.k.a. poorly written) to post here. However you can replicate the error by creating a new survey consisting of a single 'descriptive text' question and attaching this code. Here `jq` refers to Jquery

```
Qualtrics.SurveyEngine.addOnload(function(){
    /*Place Your Javascript Below This Line*/
    jq('.QuestionBody').append('<button>This shouldn\'t do anything</button>') 
});
```

This link is an example of the above.

https://sydneypsy.qualtrics.com/SE/?SID=SV_1ZGMxfENT0ykxBr

Why does this happen? Does anyone know to prevent it?

Comment: Simple solution here. I'll post it as an answer as well in case anyone is looking for this in qualtrics. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985802/why-does-a-button-cause-my-whole-web-page-to-reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Source: robbrit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985802/why-does-a-button-cause-my-whole-web-page-to-reload)

This is the default behaviour of a button. If you want to change it, do something like this:

```
$("button selector").click( function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

In your case, I would give the button an ID to use for a selector.